# How to Implement PlaceAutocompleteFragment and PlaceAutocompleteActivity to get Place details

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am using [Google Place](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/?hl=en) to get place details. Google provide different way to implement Google Place API to get place details.Different way are like **PlaceAutocompleteFragment** , **PlaceAutocompleteActivity** . How differentiate these all and how to implement to get place details using Google place API.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First of all need to [API key](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) and Enable Google Place API to search and get place details.
Add your API key to your app manifest ,need to replacing YOUR_API_KEY with your own API key:

```
<application>
  ...
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

1) **PlaceAutocompleteFragment**

Xml:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
  />
```

Java:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

/*
* The following code example shows setting an AutocompleteFilter on a PlaceAutocompleteFragment to
* set a filter returning only results with a precise address.
*/
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
        .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
        .build();
autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());//get place details here
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

2) **PlaceAutocompleteActivity**

```
private void callPlaceAutocompleteActivityIntent() {
    try {
        Intent intent =
                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                        .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
//PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE is integer for request code
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //autocompleteFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place:" + place.toString());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope its help.

Edit: change `requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED` to `resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED`

Comment: how will you select from the autocomplete list and show it on map

Comment: @SrishtiRoy . Need to try [PlaceCompleteAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter)

Comment: @pRaNaY how to customize the appearance of PlaceAutoCompleteFragment with the nearby Views in layout

Comment: `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);` returns null...

Comment: Would you mind posting your imports?  I have a compilation error on 'autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(...)'.  After the assignment of autocompleteFragment via 'PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = ...' the only options that popup after entering the "autocompleteFragment." are "instantiationException" and "SavedState".  I assume there's something wrong with my imports, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @JohnWard: Check my example repo [MainActivity](https://github.com/pranaypatel512/PlaceAutocomplete/blob/android/app/src/main/java/com/placeautocompletefragmentDemo/app/MainActivity.java) for same example,which helps you to resolve your conflicts.

Comment: @RaphaelRoyer-Rivard : you need to add fragment in your XML : see my example XML [here](https://github.com/pranaypatel512/PlaceAutocomplete/blob/android/app/src/main/res/layout/content_main.xml)

Comment: Works flawlessly for me, thank you kindly! Also, if you guys just want the looks of the autocomplete fragment but don't want to struggle implementing it, just change `Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(this);` to `Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).build(this);`. Maybe it is a little obvious but I struggled for a while.

Comment: Don't forget to add this: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0' `

Comment: I have done the same. But when I write some place to search, it disappears. What would be the problem?

Comment: @WaqasAhmedAnsari : make sure you enable google place API in your API console and your API key properly configure with your SHA1. You get proper guide to configure place API here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup

Comment: I've done all. I've implemented some functions on map too, like adding marker and line. The problem is only with search

Comment: Don't forget to enable Places API i Google Console or you will face an issue, of loosing focus of the PlaceAutocomplete, when clicking it. Check out Logcat for more info. You can use the onError callback.