# Adding PlaceAutocompleteFragment to an activity throws error

Tags: android, autocomplete

I wanted to implement PlaceAutocompleteFragment [based on the docs,](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget) in my app but when I add this snippet

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
  />
```

the last line throws "cannot resolve symbol 'PlaceAutocompleteFragment'." Why is that?

Comment: Check this implementation http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/

Comment: did you add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cannot resolve symbol PlaceAutocompleteFragment.

The compiler cannot find the class. This means that the class has not been imported properly, the name is misspelt  or the class simply does not exist.

Just add this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

**Finally**

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
              }
```

You can visit **[How to Implement PlaceAutocompleteFragment and PlaceAutocompleteActivity to get Place details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416817/how-to-implement-placeautocompletefragment-and-placeautocompleteactivity-to-get)**

Comment: Let me feedback please .

Comment: that was it. I simply deleted my old play services version and replaced it with the one you provided now it is all good. I appreciate it, I wish Google improve the way they prepare the docs ugh.

Comment: @The_Martian Move ahead .

Answer (score 1):

The class was not found by the compiler. You have to import the class by adding following code snippet in your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
```